# Book narrated by the devil

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a book that I read around 2003-2005 and I have a feeling it was relatively recent then.

I believe the main character or narrator was the devil but he was living as a normal human. I don't have a lot to go on but I remember really enjoying the book. I also think perhaps it snowed in hell, or hell froze over?

Any help would be appreciated to find this book again! Also, I think the author was male but I could be wrong.

Comment: Do you remember anything else? Other characters, plot elements, setting period? Comedy or drama?

Comment: This is a long shot, but you might check out `For Love of Evil` by Piers Anthony.  (The main character becomes the devil about a quarter of the way through the story, IIRC.)

Comment: Another, perhaps longer shot: [The Screwtape Letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Screwtape_Letters) (classic!).

Comment: Definitely a long shot, but a great book. @Wikis

Answer (score 3):

Possibly Glen Duncan's 2003 novel [*I, Lucifer.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004KAB59G)

From the Amazon link:

> The End is nigh, and the Prince of Darkness has been given one last
>   shot at redemption, if he can manage to live out a reasonably
>   blameless life on earth. As a trial run, he negotiates a month of
>   "trying without buying" in the body of struggling writer Declan Gunn.
>   ("Incarnation, the angelic drug of choice. Unlike cocaine, not to be
>   sniffed at.") Luce seizes the opportunity to binge on earthly
>   delights, to straighten the biblical record (Adam, it's hinted, was a
>   misguided variation on the Eve design), to celebrate his favorite
>   achievements (Elton John, for one), and to try to get his screenplay
>   sold, but the experience of walking among us isn't what His Majesty
>   expected: instead of teaching us what it's like to be him, Lucifer
>   finds himself understanding what it's like to be human.

I don't see any reference to snow in Hell, but maybe you're thinking of this passage in chapter 26:

> I never really wanted this job. (As all dictators whine.) Trouble was,
>   when we found ourselves in Hell everyone looked at me. (How to
>   describe Hell? Disembowelled landscape busy with suffering, incessant
>   heat, permanent scarlet twilight, **a swirling snowfall of ash,** the
>   stink of pain and the din of . . . If only. Hell is two things: the
>   absence of God and the presence of time. Infinite variations on that
>   theme. Doesn’t sound so bad, does it? Well, trust me.)